# Reconnecting a unix pipe to a child process

Tags: unix, process, pipe

I'm running a program `a` that requires some fixed input. Once all input is submitted, it opens a new process `b` using `execve`. `b` also accepts input but runs indefinitely.

I want to automate sending input to `a`, but yield control to the user when `b` opens. Naively, I would use a pipe, but unfortunately this causes `b` to exit immediately.

Here's the c code for a minimal reproducible example program:

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main(int argc, char*argv[ ])
{
   int myInt; 
   printf("input integer: ");
   scanf("%d", &myInt);
   printf("int: %d \n", myInt);

   char *shell[2];
   shell[0] = "/bin/sh"; // example of b
   shell[1] = NULL;
   execve(shell[0], shell, NULL);

   return 0;
}
```

My attempt:

```bash
echo "3" | ./a.out

echo "3\nls" > ./a.out # new lines are not sent to the child process either
```

Thanks in advance!

---

**EDIT**

Turns out just waiting for a little bit is enough;

```bash
(echo "42"; sleep 1; echo "ls") | ./a.out
```

Comment: Your edit is a bit surprising. How does this "yield control to the user?" I would expect `a.out` to immediately exit after the `ls` is sent.

Comment: For my use case this is sufficient, but yours fully answers the question! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tool you probably want here is `cat`. Using [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html), you can do this pretty elegantly for the example you've given.

```
cat <(echo 3) - | ./a.out
```

This concatenates the output of `echo 3` with stdin. This works in bash and zsh (and likely other modern shells).